# Will my Wordpress site become vulnerable after adding this functions which allows more HTML tags for subscribers?

Tags: functions, security, forms

I was thinking of adding the following lines of code to my `functions.php` file:

```
/**
 * Change the default list of allowed html tags
 */
add_action('init', 'edittag', 10);

function edittag() {
  define('CUSTOM_TAGS', true);
  global $allowedposttags, $allowedtags;
  $allowedposttags = array(
      'strong' => array(),
      'em' => array(),
      'ol' => array(),
      'li' => array(),
      'u' => array(),
      'ul' => array(),
      'blockquote' => array(),
      'code' => array(),
      'pre' => array(),
      'a' => array(
        'href' => array (),
        'title' => array ()),
      'img' => array(
        'src' => array ()),
  );

  $allowedtags = array(
      'strong' => array(),
      'em' => array(),
      'ol' => array(),
      'li' => array(),
      'u' => array(),
      'ul' => array(),
      'blockquote' => array(),
      'code' => array(),
      'pre' => array(),
      'a' => array(
        'href' => array (),
        'title' => array ()),
      'img' => array(
        'src' => array ()),
  );
}
```

The user will be able to add stuff using the [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) (WYSIWYG editor, so the user can't see the code), and the form belongs to the [bbPress](http://bbpress.org/) plugin:

[image]

I was wondering if my site will become vulnerable to spam, hackers, cracker, etc?

If that's the case, what's an easy way of making this stuff more secure?
**EDIT:** If I use Firebug I can see the actual HTML code:

For instance, this is what you see if you inspect a bold text (in Firefox):

```
<b _moz_dirty="">sd</b>
```

(Not sure if this is dangerous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read here](http://doctype.com/_moz_dirty) about `_moz_dirty` (Using Google would have given you the same answer - 2nd Result for "_moz_dirty"). Regarding html-stuff: You're offering the ability to add links...

Comment: @kaiser Is the ability of adding links dangerous? Should I disable that ability (How)?

Comment: @janoChen Ad "How": I'm not sure if you're making a joke... ? You posted the code above...

Comment: @kaiser Sorry, I mean, how is the ability of adding link dangerous?

Comment: @janoChen Define "dangerous". Where can you link, what impact on your site can it have? What settings have you made (comment moderation, etc.)?

Comment: @kaiser as I stated above, being hacked or spammed. The only comment moderation are a down vote button (maybe it will hie comments with 3 or more down votes), a flag button and maybe myself.

Comment: @janoChen What else do you need? You allow links to images and external resources...